# Restart a new instance of an activity already in the stack

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle, android-task

I have a home activity A, from where I open activity B. In B there are some complex views with states with data fetched from the network. From B with the press of a button I go to activity C.
Now if I press back, I go to B with the states preserved.
Problem:
I want to have a button in C and when I press it I open B but in a fresh state i.e. like it was called for the first time but the back button functionality to not break. I also want to keep activity A on the stack as the flow was.
How can I do this?

Comment: With simple straightforward programming. But wait - what about pressing back from the "fresh B" ? Back to C, then back to "filled up B" ?

Comment: @Shark: I don't understand your suggestion. Is there a problem with my post?

Answer (score 0):

To return from C to B but create a new instance of B, do this in C:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```